# Как сделать копию масcива Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я сделал запрос fetch в vue в методах, и хочу копировать массив, но всегда устанавливаеться только ссылка на него, как я могу копировать?

```
Ссылка на проект https://jsfiddle.net/2z09vk8d/14/
```

Comment: newArr = [...oldArr]

Comment: Массив в JS ссылочный тип данных, поэтому не совсем понятно что вы хотите копировать и для какой цели (возможно так было бы легче дать ответ) @entithat дал ответ как копировать содержимое а не ссылку через [деструктуризацию](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring)

Comment: я типо хочу сделать резервную копию уже готового масива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это массив из объектов и если там только данные, то можно просто скопировать через преобразование в json -
`this.newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.oldArray))`.
В случаи изменений объектов в старом массиве, в новом массиве будет старая копия.
Так же есть другие способы неглубокого/глубокого копирования объектов(и массивов с объектами), но так можно решить всё одной строчкой.

Comment: а в каком модуле в дереве vue мне нужно прописпть, тоесть где я могу писать код без метода, можете подсказать?

Comment: Вам пришло последнее сообщение?